# Angular2 material. How to get common css to create layout with material css?

Tags: angular, materialize, angular-material2

I have included material package into my first angular2 project.
[link i have followed](https://github.com/angular/material2).

And added theme to project to work with colours of buttons.

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

But i am missing important class like 
`container` , `teal` , `text-blue` (like colour options and `ligthen-<x>`).

Most importantly `row` and `col` classes to create layout. How can get all the power of `material-css` here.

I have tried to include `css` part from `CDN` and it backfired.

e.g. `md-input` there will be two border with different themes.
am i missing something here. guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I've replaced angular-material tag with angular-material2. I hope that's okay.

Comment: @camden_kid thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default css theme is missing when you install angular2-material. To make it work, apply this in the header of index.html

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or download the css locally, put in the assets folder and import it in style.css

```
@import url("./assets/css/material.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the link to the material CDN has changed.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```